# Create Azure FrontDoor with APEX custom domain using Terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-rm, azure-front-door

I want to create an Azure FrontDoor profile with custom **APEX** domain.
Follwoing these guides:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-how-to-onboard-apex-domain?pivots=front-door-standard-premium

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/cdn_frontdoor_endpoint

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cdn_frontdoor_custom_domain

I'm trying to create the A record with Terraform but getting the following error:

Error: creating/updating DNS A Record "yirmiXXXX.com" (Zone "yirmiXXXX.com" / Resource Group "yirmi-mng"): recordsets.RecordSetsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="BadRequest" Message="The provided ip address 'apex-endpoint-xxxxx.z01.azurefd.net' is not valid."

I understand that the A record should point to IP address, but I dont know the IP of the FrontDoor.

What do I miss here?
Did anyone succeeded to create this configuration using Terraform?

Thanks.

Comment: please have a look at this [PR](https://github.com/matt-FFFFFF/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/2). You can use the `id` of domain name generated by front door and pass it to `target_resource_id`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to create an A record in your DNS zone that points to the IP of an Azure Front Door endpoint, but you're getting a "The provided IP address 'apex-endpoint-xxxxx.z01.azurefd.net' is not valid" error. This error message indicates that the IP address you're providing is not a valid IP address, which makes sense because Front Door endpoints are not IP addresses, but rather are hostnames.

Instead of trying to create an A record that points to the IP of the Front Door endpoint, you'll need to create a CNAME record that points to the hostname of the Front Door endpoint.

To create a CNAME record, you can use the azurerm_dns_cname_record resource in Terraform. In the configuration, you'll need to provide the hostname of the Front Door endpoint as the record value, and your custom APEX domain as the name value.

You may find this guide helpful: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-custom-domains-create

Also, you may need to check if your DNS zone is properly set up with the correct NS records, and if your DNS zone is configured with the correct name servers.

It's possible that someone has done this configuration using Terraform, but it's always best to double check the documentation and guides provided by Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks!
The link is broken, I believe you meant to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/standard-premium/how-to-add-custom-domain#add-a-new-custom-domain

Anyway, I want to add root domain / APEX and not a sub domain.